# In Docker while binding host directory with container directory I am facing a problem

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to bindmount a directory form docker container to my host directory called `/home`, the docker container directory which I am trying to sync is named as `/test` and it contains a file called `new.txt`.

1. My Dockerfile is in `/home/sampledocker1` directory. Its contents are as follows:

   ```
   FROM ubuntu:18.04

   RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "mkdir test"]
   COPY new.txt test
   ```

   Here, local file `new.txt` available in current path.
2. I executed the below commands first I built the docker image and started the container as follows:

   ```
   docker build -t sample1:latest .  # image is created properly
   docker run -t -d  -v /home:/test sample1:latest /bin/bash
   ```

After creating container with `mount` option, I am expecting that the file `new.txt` in test folder of container would appear in my `/home` directory but it did not.

Here bindmount is not happening properly.

Answer (score 0):

By running -v option you actually override directory that already exists in the docker file.
If you run:

```
docker run -ti sample1:latest /bin/bash
```

You will find `/test/new.txt` file because it is added to the image layer with COPY command on the `Dockerfile`.

If you run:

```
docker run -ti -v /home:/test sample1:latest /bin/bash
```

You will find the contents of your computers `/home` directory in the `/test` of the docker container, because `-v` (mouted volume) overrides original image layer created with the COPY command on the `Dockerfile`.

THE SUGGESTION: Remove both `COPY` and `mkdir` commands from your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# Nothing at all
```

And mount your current directory with your `docker run` command:

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/test sample1:latest /bin/bash
```

Since your `Dockerfile` is empty, equivalent command is just running `ubuntu:18:04` image:

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/test ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
```

p.s. I changed `-d` (detached) to `-i`(interactive) on the example to make sure that you enter docker image as soon as you run `docker run` command.

Comment: I followed all the steps mentioned above and bind was happening. But it is entering interactive mode and I am unable to know whether what I am trying to install is running or not, In this case I am trying to install snort on docker. After entering interactive mode when I am executing snort command it is not happening.

Comment: so - do not use interactive mode :) It is added here only for debugging purposes.
If you want to install snort(I am not sure what that is) you most likely need to install it on the image which means on the Dockerfile. Installing packages on running container is not a good idea, because containers are not persistent, images are.